# Grails gsp encoding issue on Jboss 7

Tags: java, string, grails, encoding, character-encoding

I have a gsp file, let's say that it is kind of simple and includes just one line:

```
<t:translate language="${params.language}" value="Naložite sliko" />
```

This template is included in layout with `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>` at the top.

`t:translate` is my own tag which is an entry point to translation service. `value` attribute of this tag is used as a key for translation messages.

When application is deployed on Jboss, value that I get in taglib translate function is corrupted - it looks like NaloĹľite sliko. If I transform the string with `new String(text.getBytes("windows-1250"), "UTF-8")` i get the correct value. If I run it locally value is not corrupted.

Gsp files in tmp directory on jboss are UTF-8 encoded (checked with `file -bi`). JVM property file.encoding is also set to UTF-8 (as parameter when starting the server). Server is running on a linux virtual machine.

relevant part of Config.groovy:

```
// GSP settings
grails {
    views {
        gsp {
            encoding = 'UTF-8'
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why the string is corrupted?

```
Grails version: 2.4.2
Server: Jboss as 7.1.3.Final
Java: 1.6.0_45 (64-Bit)
Linux: CentOS 6.6 Final
```

**EDIT**

If I add `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>` to the template it starts working as expected. But still - I'm interested in what setting sets the encoding otherwise. Probably something in the environment?

Comment: Did you checked the compiler settings?

Comment: I checked the BuildConfig.groovy file and nothins strange is specified there. Also nothing that looks related to encodings.